# Why can a pointer not be assigned to an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code:

```
int *pa;

int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Why pa = a is ok, but a = pa is not allowed?

Comment: What would you expect `a = pa` to do?

Comment: The compiler thinks it's an error, a typo. I agree. Why would you declare a as an array, and then suddenly steer it away from pointing to it's data? If you wanted such functionality, you'd create a as a pointer instead, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that type of `a` is still an array but it just ***decays*** into a pointer when you do `pa=a;`. `pa` will now point to the ***first*** element of the array not the entire array itself. When you do `a=pa` it doesnot make any sense as you are trying point a datatype which is holding 3 integers to a type which can point only to a single integer.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is purely conceptual, this is not the actual reason why this happens.

I like to think of pointer assignment like OOP & Inheritance.

Imagine `int *` is a generic object. Now, think of `int []` as an object that inherits from `int *`.

As you can see, you can cast down from `int []` to `int *`, but not casting upwards.

Comment: Whilst I understand the analogy, I don't think it's helpful to confuse this issue with something that it really isn't.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth True, that's why I added the initial statement that it was purely conceptual.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple answer is that the language definition simply doesn't allow it — it's a design choice.

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.5.16 Assignment operators**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> 2 An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

And what's a modifiable lvalue?

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> 1 An *lvalue* is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than `void`;<sup>53)</sup>
> if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined.
> When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to
> designate the object. **A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that does not have array type**, does
> not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure
> or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of
> all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.
> ...
> 53) The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression `E1 = E2`, in which the left
> operand `E1` is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an
> object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described
> as the ‘‘value of an expression’’.

Emphasis added.

Array expressions in C are treated differently than most other expressions. The reason for this is explained in an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130226145628/http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html) Dennis Ritchie wrote about the development of the C language:

> NB existed so briefly that no full description of it was written. It supplied the types `int` and `char`, arrays of them, and pointers to them, declared in a style typified by:
>
> ```
> int i, j;
> char c, d;
> int iarray[10];
> int ipointer[];
> char carray[10];
> char cpointer[];
> ```
>
> The semantics of arrays remained exactly as in B and BCPL: the declarations of `iarray` and `carray` create cells dynamically initialized with a value pointing to the first of a sequence of 10 integers and characters, respectively. The declarations for `ipointer` and `cpointer` omit the size, to assert that no storage should be allocated automatically. Within procedures, the language's interpretation of the pointers was identical to that of the array variables: a pointer declaration created a cell differing from an array declaration only in that the programmer was expected to assign a referent, instead of letting the compiler allocate the space and initialize the cell.
>
> Values stored in the cells bound to array and pointer names were the machine addresses, measured in bytes, of the corresponding storage area. Therefore, indirection through a pointer implied no run-time overhead to scale the pointer from word to byte offset. On the other hand, the machine code for array subscripting and pointer arithmetic now depended on the type of the array or the pointer: to compute `iarray[i]` or `ipointer+i` implied scaling the addend i by the size of the object referred to.
>
> These semantics represented an easy transition from B, and I experimented with them for some months. Problems became evident when I tried to extend the type notation, especially to add structured (record) types. Structures, it seemed, should map in an intuitive way onto memory in the machine, but in a structure containing an array, there was no good place to stash the pointer containing the base of the array, nor any convenient way to arrange that it be initialized. For example, the directory entries of early Unix systems might be described in C as:
>
> ```
> struct {
>     int    inumber;
>     char   name[14];
> };
> ```
>
> I wanted the structure not merely to characterize an abstract object but also to describe a collection of bits that might be read from a directory. Where could the compiler hide the pointer to `name` that the semantics demanded? Even if structures were thought of more abstractly, and the space for pointers could be hidden somehow, how could I handle the technical problem of properly initializing these pointers when allocating a complicated object, perhaps one that specified structures containing arrays containing structures to arbitrary depth?
>
> **The solution constituted the crucial jump in the evolutionary chain between typeless BCPL and typed C. It eliminated the materialization of the pointer in storage, and instead caused the creation of the pointer when the array name is mentioned in an expression. The rule, which survives in today's C, is that values of array type are converted, when they appear in expressions, into pointers to the first of the objects making up the array.**
>
> This invention enabled most existing B code to continue to work, despite the underlying shift in the language's semantics. The few programs that assigned new values to an array name to adjust its origin—possible in B and BCPL, meaningless in C—were easily repaired. More important, the new language retained a coherent and workable (if unusual) explanation of the semantics of arrays, while opening the way to a more comprehensive type structure.

It's a good article, and well worth reading if you're interested in the "whys" of C.